# change highlight color of drop down list in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down list with 4 items inside . A blue highlight appears when I select one item from it. I want to change that color .. Is it possible?

I have tried following :

I am executing this code on ommouseover of option item(I tried for on click also)

```
option = document.getElementById("option1");   
option.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
```

The code is executed but color is not applied .

I have read many similar posts about the same on this site but there is no post to change this blue (default) highlight color. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to tweak the styles of built-in controls such as the select box. Instead, if you need custom appearance, use a GUI toolkit like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) or [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/). They replace your controls with home-brewed controls built from divs and CSS styles, so they are completely stylable and modifiable.